For Ag grid, when define rowclick(), the other cell which defined as celleditor has dropdown list, the dropdown list can not be shown
I worked with Angular 17. Ag Grid 31.
My requirement is that, I need to define section to display as row. And click the section, the data below the section would disappear.
And the data contains dropdown list, if I defined row click function, then the dropdown list would not appear when I click the cell. How can I fix this issue.
And when I define any function for cell click, the dropdown list would not appear as well.
My html
      <ag-grid-angular style="width: 49.75rem; height: 500px;" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [getRowHeight]="getRowHeight"
        [rowData]="filteredRowData" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [autoSizeStrategy]="autoSizeStrategy"
        class='ag-theme-quartz' [singleClickEdit]="true"
        (rowClicked)="handleSectionRowClick($event)"></ag-grid-angular>,

My data, the section appears as the merged cells
    public rowData: any[] | null = [
        { section: 'Fluid', jan: 'Fluid' },
        { jan: 534, feb: 612, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 765, feb: 146, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 335, feb: 122, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'enum' },
        { jan: 35, feb: 342, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 568, feb: 531, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 365, feb: 361, mar: 243, apr: 231, may: 428, jun: 231, type: 'Fluid', dataType: 'string' },
        { section: 'Cement', jan: 'Cement' },
        { jan: 21, feb: 12, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 28, jun: 31, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 21, feb: 12, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 28, jun: 31, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 21, feb: 12, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 28, jun: 31, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 21, feb: 12, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 28, jun: 31, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 2, feb: 32, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 48, jun: 21, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' },
        { jan: 21, feb: 12, mar: 24, apr: 31, may: 28, jun: 31, type: 'Cement', dataType: 'string' }
    ];

My column definition
    public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
        {
            headerName: 'Code Name',
            field: 'jan',
      editable: false,
            colSpan: (params: ColSpanParams) => {
                if (isHeaderRow(params)) {
                    return 6;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Value Code',
            field: 'feb',
            cellEditor: (params: ICellEditorParams) => {
                if (params.data.dataType === 'enum') {
                    return 'agSelectCellEditor';
                } else {
                    return null; // 使用默认的长文本框
                }
            },
            cellEditorParams: (params: ICellEditorParams) => {
                if (params.data.dataType === 'enum') {
                    return { values: [111, 222] };
                } else {
                    return null; // 使用默认的cellEditorParams
                }
            }
        },
        { headerName: 'UoM', field: 'mar' },
        { headerName: 'Parameter Description', field: 'jun' },
    {
      headerName: "Select Editor",
      field: 'mar' ,
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: this.languages,
      } as ISelectCellEditorParams,
    },
    ];

My row click function
    handleSectionRowClick(event:any) {
    if (event.data.section) {
      this.sectionExpanded[event.data.section] = !this.sectionExpanded[event.data.section];
    }
    }

My UI:
enter image description here
I need the dropdown list col to appear and the row click is working

According to the code snippet you provided, I supplemented the languages variable (fixed value), and the dropdown menu can be displayed normally when running. I suspect that the dropdown menu is not displayed due to other reasons, such as languages being passed as mutable parameters through @Input. If you could provide more detailed code, it would be easier to pinpoint the problem.

I dont have more code. But I want to share you one detail. If I define "RowClick" or "CellClick" event, the behavior would be the same. The dropdown would show and disappear immediately.

Since the issue you described cannot be reproduced based on the code snippet you provided, it's difficult to confirm the root cause. I speculate if there is any code that re-renders the table when the click event is triggered.
